# Sorting within each category separately in R

Tags: r

I have a set of almost 4000 data points, each specifying a time at which an incident happened and a site at which it happened, and there are 165 sites.  I want a list of inter-incident times at each site.

If there were just one site, I would sort the times into increasing order (t_1 < t_2 < ... < t_n) and then find the differences s_{n+1} = t_{n+1}-t_n.  But I want to do this separately at each site.

Ultimately each data point will specify a site and a list of inter-incident times.

Another complication: it may be worth keeping the inter-incident times in chronological order.

The R commands

```
sort(times)
```

and

```
site[order(times)]
```

would get me somewhere if I didn't want to do this for each site separately.

How can I do this in R?

Comment: You can `order` by more than one variable at a time - `order(df$group,df$time)` - also take a look at `ave` then for comparing within groups, e.g. `ave(df$time, df$group, FUN=function(x) c(NA,diff(x)) )` It also might be worth investigating the `data.table` and `dplyr` packages, which allow a lot of functions to be applied within groups.

Comment: I'm still digesting the answers and comments.  I'll be back.....

Comment: This question has been down-voted twice.  Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 2):

using `dplyr`, something like this, depending on how your data is laid out (a dput would help):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(site) %>%
       arrange(times) %>%
       mutate(difference = c(0, diff(times)))
```

Comment: The problem I see is that `diff`ing the entire vector introduces some "crazy" values inter-sites (the diff from last time of site A to first value of site B). Anyway, without a reproducible example, it's difficult to match desired output

Comment: I don;t think so - it's looping over each site as a new data frame, so each starts with 0.

Comment: ok, I'm back.  I got this error message: Error in UseMethod("regroup") : 
  no applicable method for 'regroup' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @jeremycg : Do you know what needs to be done about the error message mentioned in the comment above?

Comment: you'll need to dput(df), looks like you have something weird with your data

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to know what exactly your data looks like and, specially, what your desired output looks like without a reproducible example or sample data.

That said, I think you could use the package `data.table` to achieve what you want:

```
set.seed(1)
a<-data.table(time=sample(1:1000,100,F),site=sample(letters[1:8],100,T))
a[,.SD,by=site][order(site,time)][,.(list(diff(time))),by=site]
```

That creates a list with all inter-accident times at each site. It works because `data.table` understands expressions instead of functions, so instructing it `.(list(...))` or what is equivalent `list(list(...))` makes it, well, produce a list.

If you want an average (or whatever else function on times you might want) of the times, then:

```
a[,.SD,by=site][order(site,time)][,mean(diff(time)),by=site]
```

will work.